# Find Table Row Index using jQuery

Tags: jquery, indexing, row

I'm an intermediate user in jQuery. I know to find the rowIndex of a table using jQUery, but my scenario is a different one. My table(GridView) consists of 20 columns and each column with different controls like textbox, dropdownlist, image, label. All are server side controls in each row. I bind the gridview with the records from the database. Now when I click on any control or onchange of any textbox, I need to get the rowIndex of that changed column's row. Here is the code I've user:

```
$("#gv1 tr input[name $= 'txtName']").live('click', function(e){
   alert($(this).closest('td').parent().attr('sectionRowIndex'));
});
```

But I'm unable to get the rowIndex. If I use any html control inside the gridview, I'm able to get the rowIndex. Is there any way to find out the rowIndex when a server control inside the gridview is clicked?

Comment: Instead of `.attr("sectionRowIndex")` use `.prop("sectionRowIndex")` Real life working example from my project: `$("#diagnose").html( $(e).parent().prop("sectionRowIndex") );`

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

```
var rowIndex = $(this)
    .closest('tr') // Get the closest tr parent element
    .prevAll() // Find all sibling elements in front of it
    .length; // Get their count
```

Comment: But I wanna get the rowIndex of the changed Textbox?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML of your page?

Comment: <tr>

  <td>
     <span id="gv1_ctl02_lblID">1</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="gv1_ctl02_txtName" value="Achu" name="gv1$ctl02$txtName"/>
                 </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" value="Madurai" id="txtLocation"/>
  </td>

</tr>

When I click on gv1_ctl02_txtName, I won't get the rowIndex, but when I click on "txtLocation", I'm able to get.

Comment: In your selector `"#gv1 tr input[name $= 'txtName']"` you take only the inputs whose name ends with `txtName`, so it should work fine for the `gv1$ctl02$txtName` textbox and not for the `txtLocation` textbox.

Comment: No, it alerts rowIndex as '0' for all rows. But for txtLocation, it returns the correct index. txtLocation is an HTML control!

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov,

          Your code doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: this gives the wrong rowIndex if there is a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. try `$(this).closest('tr')[0].rowIndex`

Answer (score 9):

`sectionRowIndex` is a property of the `<tr>` element, not an attribute.

The correct way to modify your sample code is to access the jQuery item with a zero indexer like this:

```
$("#gv1 tr input[name $= 'txtName']").live('click', function(e){
   alert($(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex);
});
```

This will return the correct row index for you. Also, if you are going to use jQuery's `.closest()` function to traverse up the DOM and also `.parent()`, why not compine those two and just traverse up to the closest `<tr>` element?

```
$("#gv1 tr input[name $= 'txtName']").live('click', function(e){
   alert($(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex);
});
```

This will also handle weird cases where the parent->child relationship isn't exactly what you expected. For example if you chained a `$(this).parent().parent()` and then decided to wrap your inner cell with another div or span, you might screw up the relationship. The `.closest()` is the easy way out to make sure it will always work.

Of course my code samples are re-using your provided sample above. You may wish to test with a simpler selector first to prove it works, then refine your selectors.

Comment: Since it is a property and not an attribute, the OP could just swap `attr('sectionRowIndex)` with `prop('sectionRowIndex')`. I tried it, it works.

Answer (score 4):

This is for a checkbox in the table cell, on change:

```
 var row = $(this).parent().parent();
 var rowIndex = $(row[0].rowIndex);
 console.log(rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be able to just use:

```
var rowIndex = $(this).parents("tr:first")[0].rowIndex;
```