# onChange triggers only once in a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

i have the following problem:
I have a table with 2 input elements. If one of them bigger than the other, the whole row is supposed to be colored accordingly to the comparison. I trigger this with an onchange event and the first time while loading the site. The procedures work fine, but the onchange event only get triggered in 1 of 4 changes.

The table statement is the following:

```
<div class="grid">
 <table id="table" class="tableRegion w100">
  <thead style="text-align:left">
   <tr>
    <fmt:bundle basename="res/web/ec_resources">
     <td class="tableHeader">
    ...
     </td> ...
    </fmt:bundle>
   </tr>
  </thead>      
  <tbody>
   <c:set var="i" value="0"/>
   <c:forEach var="participation" items="${someForm.list}">
     <tr id="participationRow${i}">
```

And in here the code for the table > tr > td:

```
<td class="right bottom nowrap">
 <div>
  <c:out value="${someForm.event.currency.code}"/>
  <fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" var="ovFee" value="${overallFee}" />
  <c:if test="${someForm.array[i].feeDebit != 0.0}">
   <spring:input class="right debit" path="array[${i}].feeDebit" maxlength="7" size="6" onchange="isPaid(${i});" />
  </c:if><c:if test="${someForm.array[i].feeDebit == 0.0}">
   <spring:input class="right debit" path="array[${i}].feeDebit" maxlength="7" size="6" onchange="isPaid(${i});" value="${ovFee}"/>
  </c:if>
 </div>
</td>

<td class="right bottom nowrap">
 <div class="padT5"><c:out value="${someForm.event.currency.code}"/> <spring:input class="right paid" path="array[${i}].feePaid" maxlength="7" size="6" onchange="isPaid(${i});"/></div>
</td>
```

The skript being called is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table > tbody > tr').each(function(i) {
        var paid = parseFloat($(this).find('input.paid').val());
        var debit = parseFloat($(this).find('input.debit').val());
        if (paid == debit)
            $('#participationRow'+i).addClass("green");
        else if (paid > debit)
            $('#participationRow'+i).addClass("yellow");
        }
    );
});

function isPaid(i){
    var paid = parseFloat($('#participationRow'+i).find('input.paid').val());
    var debit = parseFloat($('#participationRow'+i).find('input.debit').val());
    if (paid == debit)
        $('#participationRow'+i).addClass("green");
    else if (paid > debit)
        $('#participationRow'+i).addClass("yellow");

}
```

What is the reason for the event being triggered just once in a while? I cross-checked with jQuery and onclick. They all get only triggered once in a while. No matter if I leave by clicking away or tabbing away.

Comment: Have you tried a event called [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: thats what I meant by: "I cross-checked with jQuery". I tried $('input[type=text]').change(function(){...});
Did not bring any more success...

Comment: I think you may have the problem with passing the i value. Check it with a alert box in isPaid function.

Comment: the i-parameter is transferred correctly. The code is working. But only once in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... looking a while and with the help of @kabaros und @Flater I found the following which worked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input.paid').change(function(){
  var i = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex;
  isPaid(i);
 });
```

The solution was the `$('input.paid')` which got triggered, rather than `$('input')`. And counting the row was not that easy as well, but the above code counts the rows right. Unfortunately the `onchange` in the `input`-field only triggers once in a while!

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks any definition of a trigger when this is supposed to run.

The first part (the `.each()` block) is only executed on `$(document).ready();`, which means it is executed once per page load (right after the document has finished loading.)

The `isPaid()` function is nothing more than a function, I don't see where it is being called as it is not present in the current code snippet.

Your code seems OK by itself, but it just lacks any form of trigger.

You would expect something like:

```
$("input").change(function() {

    var the_row = $(this).parent().parent(); //finds the <tr> it belongs to.
    var i = the_row.attr("id").replace("participationRow","");

    isPaid(i);
});
```

There are ways to improve on this, but this is the vital key you're missing in your code.

Comment: The `isPaid()` Function is being called in the spring:input here:  `<spring:input class="right debit" path="array[${i}].feeDebit" maxlength="7" size="6" onchange="isPaid(${i});" />`
But I will test your suggestions next, although I am most certainly I tried your solution in some form.

Comment: Sorry... no change. The same thing happens. Although I could not find one time, where your solution worked at least once. =(

Comment: If you change the content of the change function to a simple `alert("I am triggered");`, does the alert also fire once in a while instead of every tyme the content of an input field is changed?

Comment: No, that's the problem. He does not trigger the event "change". Not by onchange="isPaid(${i});" nor by $("input").change()

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the setup of the page, this is a standard javascript feature. The table gets rendered during the orignial page load? (not via Ajax or partial views or ...)? Also, I see that you use `#table` in the selector. This means the ID of the <table> is `table` ?

Comment: No, the tableid isn't actual `table`, it's a bit more complicated and completely unique on the site. I checked that.
The statement for the table, will be added on the original post!

Comment: Your code `var i = the_row.attr("id").replace...` is wrong. WebDeveloper calls an false function. With @kabaros call the event get's triggered!

Comment: Kabaros uses the exact same way of setting up a trigger. Also, the string replace works; I have used it in numerous projects. If used numerically, it needs an int.parse, but in this case it is only used to concatenate back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function highlightIfPaid(i){
        var paid = parseFloat($('#participationRow'+i).find('input.paid').val());
        var debit = parseFloat($('#participationRow'+i).find('input.debit').val());
        if (paid == debit)
            $('#participationRow'+i).addClass("green");
        else if (paid > debit)
            $('#participationRow'+i).addClass("yellow");
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //just use jquery for binding to change event,
        //my guess is that Spring doesn't have a value for i at the point and jquery is not loaded by then so $ is undefined
        $('input.debit').change(function(){
            //you need to get the index i based on your table structure
            //I assumed this is just the index of the row
            //I get this method from this other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620391/find-table-row-index-using-jquery
            var i = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;
            highlightIfPaid(i);
        });

//Dry: highlight your rows on first load
$('#table > tbody > tr').each(highlightIfPaid);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this works particularly. In @Flater answer the "class" was missing. If that is found, it gets triggered. Unfortunately, nor your function for calculating the "i" nor the one of Flater is working correctly.

Comment: if you copy paste the html output from the browser, we can see the output and see exactly how you can do it

Comment: As I found, your counting something different than the row, I think, because the first row is 2, the second is 5, the third is 8 in your example.
But the rest is working